# Is it possible to see what user activity an Android app is monitoring / tracking and what data it's sending back to it's servers about the user?

Tags: android, tracking, privacy

I would like to check the user activity an app is tracking. The Audible app specifically.

e.g. does it log every tap? Does it log how long each session is etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, no.  Computers are not capable of this sort of sophisticated reasoning about a program's possible behaviors (see, for example, the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which shows that an algorithm can't even determine if a given program will finish running).  Only a human reverse-engineering the software by hand could possibly make this determination, which would be a very time-consuming process for an app of even moderate complexity.

Comment: Thank you Ryan M!

Comment: Glad it helped!  If you think this is the correct answer to the question, feel free to mark it as accepted to help anyone who might find this in the future.